How does the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{a_n}$ imply convergence of $\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k \to 0$?
For $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $a_n \uparrow \infty $, I am given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{a_n}$ converges.
I need to prove that as $n\to\infty$, the sequence $\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \to 0$.
How do I even begin with this? I tried comparison tests, etc. but nothing seems to work. Please help.

That is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma
